# Is it possible to manipulate the arguments array in beforeRoute() for the route handler?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have a case where an element of a pattern path can be interpreted differently. These are all valid paths:

```
/items              // 1) all items, page 1
/items/2            // 2) all items, page 2, 3, 4, etc.
/items/2018         // 3) all items published in '2018', page 1
/items/2018/2       // 4) all items published in '2018', page 2, 3, 4, etc.
/items/name         // 5) all items published by 'name', page 1
/items/name/2       // 6) all items published by 'name', page 2, 3, 4, etc.
```

And these are the routes:

```
[maps]
/items = ItemsController                    // covers 1)
/items/@filterOrOffset = ItemsController    // covers 2), 3), 5)
/items/@filter/@offset = ItemsController    // covers 4), 6)
```

As F3 does not allow RegEx in route patterns, I use the *beforeRoute* event to do the interpretation. The *BaseController* class looks like this:

```
class BaseController {

  public function beforeRoute($f3, array $arguments) {

    // – interpret $arguments, which might be @filterOrOffset or @filter & @offset 
    //   and set $arguments['year'], $arguments['name'] and $arguments['offset'],
    // – then unset $arguments['filter'] or $arguments['filterOrOffset'],
    // – then call the route handler like this:
    $method = strtolower($f3->VERB);
    $this->{$method}($f3, $arguments);
    return false;

  }

}
```

Everything works fine that way, but I somehow do not like that I call the route handler manually. I would prefer the framework to call the route handler (by removing the last three lines), but I do not know how to handover the manipulated arguments array. I tried it by setting $f3->PARAMS but to no avail.

Comment: Not very consistent routing behavior.. how do you route to page 2018? As far as I know you cannot alter the arguments. You can use PARAMS everywhere or just keep your current code. There’s nothing wrong about calling the method manually yourself. But I would think about the routings once more. Why not using something like /items/year-2018/1 to make the routing parameters more obvious

Comment: Not very consistent routing behavior.. 
–> It is for the users of the website, which is up and running since 2008.
how do you route to page 2018?
–> /items/@filterOrOffset = ItemsController plus 'interpretation' in beforeRoute()
 As far as I know you cannot alter the arguments.
–> That was my question.
You can use PARAMS everywhere or just keep your current code.
–> I try to avoid accessing $f3 in child classes of BaseController.
There’s nothing wrong about calling the method manually yourself.
–> Yes, I know, it just does not feel right somehow.

Comment: But I would think about the routings once more.
–> No, it makes perfect sense that way if you'd knew the context of the website.

Why not using something like /items/year-2018/1 to make the routing parameters more obvious
–> Just makes it less readable.